# Two independent solutions for diffussion equation?

Tags: linear-pde

I have this equation to solve
\begin{equation}
\partial_t F = \partial^2_y F
\end{equation}
and got two independent solutions through some trial and error.

\begin{equation}
F_1 = erf\left(\frac{y}{2\sqrt{t}}\right) \\
F_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\exp\left( \frac{-y^2}{4{t}}\right)
\end{equation}
I'm wondering how many other possible solutions exist to this equation. I'll be glad to be directed to a chapter in some mathematics text that deals with the number of solutions for a linear partial differential equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are whole books on this. For the Diffusion Equation, you can't do better than [*The Mathematics of Diffusion*](https://smile.amazon.com/Mathematics-Diffusion-Oxford-Science-Publications/dp/0198534116/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1523367502&sr=8-1&keywords=the%20mathematics%20of%20diffusion), by J. Crank. Another classic is [*Conduction of Heat in Solids*](https://smile.amazon.com/Conduction-Solids-Oxford-Science-Publications/dp/0198533683/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1523367784&sr=8-1&keywords=conduction%20of%20heat%20in%20solids), by Carslaw and Jaeger.